# Google sheet - merge two ranges in on ranges with all columns

Tags: join, google-sheets, merge, google-sheets-formula

I don't know why I don't find a solution about this problem on the internet
And I don't know why it is not possible with a simple formula ... ^^

So, here is my question, in one screenshot
[image]

How can I "merge", **with a formula**, two ranges into one.

For explaination, I would like to merge some datas from 2 differents sheets, but both have same "key" (i.e, I have the same number of row for two ranges, it's sure. It's like a join in SQL, but datas are already sorted and every row will join one time)

Anyone knows how I can do it ?
I tried split, concat, query, flatten, arrayformula, etc. and nothing =/

Thanks a lot for your help :)

Here is a sheet to copy/paste datas
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1F9OO760arByMehbhJgZkLaE_a6TgGUipmrzMqnzeT0o/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73767719/5632629

Answer (score 2):

you can do simple:

```
={A2:B\ D2:D}
```

note that both of these ranges need to have an equal amount of rows

[image]

Comment: Oh my god, why it is so complicated to find this simple solution on the internet ^^ ... Thanks a lot ! Again ! :)

Comment: Apparently (using chat-GPT to explain this: comma not working (giving a "Formula parse error"), but backslash works fine!), I get:

Using {A1:B10 \ D1:E10} is an alternative syntax that's not as commonly documented but can indeed work for combining ranges side by side in certain locales or specific versions of Google Sheets.

Comment: @zigah https://stackoverflow.com/q/73767719/5632629

Answer (score 0):

The above answer (no longer?) works or there is some error in how it is being displayed. The backslash is the problem, changing it to a comma works for me.

`={A2:B, D2:D}`